# the body of functiuon cannot be an iterator block

Tags: c#

Strugling with async method has to return `IEnumerable`

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<SitemapHeirachy>> GetLocations(string culture, string parent, string product, Geo geoSolution, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var locations = await _locationService.GetAllLocations(culture, cancellationToken);
    var locationsValue = locations.GetValueOrLogError("Unable to Get All locations", _logger);
    if (locations != null)
    {
        foreach (var locationEntity in locationsValue ?? Enumerable.Empty<Location>())
        {
            yield return new SitemapHeirachy(locationEntity.Name, GetPrefix(locationEntity.Name, product))
            {
                Links = null
            };
        }
    }
}
```

receiving error message

> the body of GetLocations cannot be an iterator block beacause `Task<IEnumerable<SitemapHeirachy>>` is not an iterator interface type

have to make this method async it's been working without async however the locations variable was not invoked by await

i've been using locations.Result.Value which is not the best practice. Now i'm strugling for rewriting it to async.

Please, could you help me to figure out the solution? I understand why its calling an error, however how to mend it - no clue :(*

Comment: You can't `yield return` in an async method

Comment: How to fix your code depends on the underlying collection type that GetAllLocations uses, and whether or not you want to create an in-memory collection in your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use Enumerable with async, you can use [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=net-8.0) which available since C# 8

```cs
private async IAsyncEnumerable<SitemapHeirachy> GetLocations(string culture, string parent, string product, Geo geoSolution, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var locations = await _locationService.GetAllLocations(culture, cancellationToken);
    var locationsValue = locations.GetValueOrLogError("Unable to Get All locations", _logger);
    if (locations != null)
    {
        foreach (var locationEntity in locationsValue ?? Enumerable.Empty<Location>())
        {
            yield return new SitemapHeirachy(locationEntity.Name, GetPrefix(locationEntity.Name, product))
            {
                Links = null
            };
        }
    }
}
```

iterate over it AS following

```
await foreach(var sitemap in GetLocations(/*your parm*/))
{
    // do what ever you want asynchronically
}
```

read more on [Iterating with Async Enumerables in C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use yield. Or use IAsyncEnumerable if iteration is asynchronous.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<SitemapHeirachy>> GetLocations(string culture, string parent, string product, Geo geoSolution, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var locations = await _locationService.GetAllLocations(culture, cancellationToken);
    var locationsValue = locations.GetValueOrLogError("Unable to Get All locations", _logger);
    return locationsValue?.Select(locationEntity => new SitemapHeirachy(locationEntity.Name, GetPrefix(locationEntity.Name, product))
            {
                Links = null
            }) ?? Enumerable.Empty<SitemapHeirachy>();
}
```